# Use multiple SSL certificates per domain with HAProxy

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, reverse-proxy, haproxy

When the SSL certificate is revoked, some browsers (including modern ones) don't fetch the new certificate from the server, so about 0.1% of the clients are getting "Revoked certificate" error page and they can't access the service securely. The problem on the client side is solved by clearing browser's cache. However not everybody does it. Most people just close the page as fast as they can, as the error message tends to say "the authenticity of the received data could not be verified" and "report this broken site"..

Is there a way to configure HAProxy, which is working as SSL offloader in front of the web server cluster, to allow connections to be established using the "old" certificate, while all the negotiations and renegotiations are served using the "new" certificate?

P.S. This problem is partially caused by HAProxy SSL session cache, which is crucial with our load, so it can't be disabled.

Comment: *"When the SSL certificate is revoked, some browsers (including modern ones) don't fetch the new certificate from the server"* - the problem statement is not clear to me. SSL/TLS is a network control, and I've never heard of caching at the network level, like certificates. There are continuity schemes at higher levels, but they are not caching *per se* (and they are kind of rare). Is this a bad interaction with [HPKP](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-websec-key-pinning-20)? I think Chrome and Firefox are doing it, but I'm not sure the symptoms sound correct.

Comment: @jww I did not say that certificate is cached, I've just said that clearing browser's cache was the only way to solve this problem on Chrome, Firefox and latest IE. I don't know what happens in the background when cache is cleared, possibly all SSL sessions are cleaned up or all certificate information is deleted too, so on next connection full certificate verification is done. Nevertheless, the only way to fix this is to clear browser's cache. The problem is: the connection to the server is rejected and person can't use the service, even though a valid certificate is being sent out already.

Answer (score 1):

The certificate of he server is sent inside each full handshake and a validation of the certificate is only done when a certificate is received and is done against the received certificate, not anything cached. But, it might happen that clients refuse to establish a connection if the fingerprint of the certificates does not match the one they've received earlier within the browser session. Or it might be, that they use implicit certificate pinning (with a browser extension), which will detect if the new certificate conflicts with an earlier received certificate and complain about it.

There is nothing you can do about it. All you get from the client at the start of the SSL handshake is the ClientHello record. This might contain the name of the target host (if SNI is used) but there is no information about any old certificates the client might have seen. This means, that the server has no information on which it could decide, if it should send the new or the older certificate for the same hostname.

Comment: The problem is the SSL session cache: http://bit.ly/1sKERGw The SSL session established using the "old" certificate will stay live as soon as the browser is open. The server (HAProxy) receives the full handshake only once for each Keep-Alive session (and normally there are about 5) and the server also caches the SSL session by it's ID, so it can be loaded from cache upon next request without the need to renegotiate. I simply need HAProxy to either send HelloRequest to client or to wait until a session is pulled from SSL session cache and cause a renegotiation then.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is really the reason. Session resuming is just an offer, but if  the client offers to resume a session which the server does not have any longer it will simply result in not resuming the session and doing the full handshake (with the new certificate) instead. And the server should abandon cached sessions at restart or at least if it has different certificates.

Comment: Yes, that actually solved the "problem", but during the restart the connections were dropped. I guess it's a different issue to take care of. Restarting seems to be the only "staright forward" solution without writing own modules. HAProxy documentation has nothing on this and I doubt they will ever support something so specific.